# Setting a variable to 0 in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Is it possible to set a variable to `0` (or any other number) in LLVM-IR ? My searches have found me the following 3 line snippet, but is there anything simpler than the following solution ?

```
%ptr = alloca i32                               ; yields i32*:ptr
store i32 3, i32* %ptr                          ; yields void
%val = load i32, i32* %ptr                      ; yields i32:val = i32 3
```

Comment: If you just want to set a pre-existing memory location to 0, the second line is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLVM-IR is in static single assignment (SSA) form, so each variable is only assigned once. If you want to assign a value to a memory region you can simply use a store operation as you showed in your example:

```
store i32 3, i32* %ptr
```

The type of the second argument is `i32*` which means that it is a pointer to an integer that is 32 bit long.

Answer (score 3):

To set a value to zero (or null in general) you can use

```
Constant::getNullValue(Type)
```

and to set a value with an arbitrary constant number you can use `ConstantInt::get()`, but you need to identify the context first, like this:

```
LLVMContext &context = function->getContext();
/* or BB->getContext(), BB can be any basic block in the function */
Value* constVal = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(context), 3);
```